# Delegate mouseenter and click event don't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

### Prologue

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application. The only fixed content in this app is the navigation bar at the top, the rest of the body is all dynamically appended to a `<div id="bodyArea">` element through classic Ajax calls to action methods.

When clicking on the "Ricerca" (*search*) button, a search form appears. User type in what s/he's looking for, hit enter and a list of items is shown like this:

[image]

This is the HTML of the resulting page:

```
<div id="bodyArea" class="container min-100">
    <div id="FormRicerca"> 
         // search bar
    </div>
    <div id="EsitoRicerca">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th scope="col">...</th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>...</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** the `<div id="FormRicerca">` element is generated when the user click on the button in the navigation bar. When actual search is performed, the `<div id="EsitoRicerca">` is appended, containing the search result.

### Desired output

To give users access to employees' details without any additional buttons, I wanted to make all the rows clickable, adding an outwards shadow on mouse hover.

### Problem

Starting from the shadow, I placed this jQuery function within the usual `$(document).ready(function () {...})` block where other working functions are:

```
$('#bodyArea').on("mouseenter", "tr", function () {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

but nothing happened. I thought that maybe the `mouseenter` event was a little "picky" (never used before) so I started with a simple `click` event, to check whether was an event problem or a binding problem, but nothing again. Further, I went higher in the delegate element and was more specific in the selector:

```
$('body').on("click", "table tbody tr", function () {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

but still, the event isn't being fired.

**EDIT:**

This is the whole .js file where the function is. The other two ajax calls are working fine, but they are appended at an earlier stage:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on("click", "#AvvioRicerca", function () {
        var ambito = $('#AmbitoRicerca')[0].selectedIndex;
        var chiave = $('#ChiaveRicerca').val();
        var url = $('#AvvioRicerca').data()["url"];

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                ambito: ambito,
                chiave: chiave
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            $('#EsitoRicerca').removeClass('invisible');
            $('#EsitoRicerca').html(response);
        });
    });

    $('body').on("keypress", "#ChiaveRicerca", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var ambito = $('#AmbitoRicerca')[0].selectedIndex;
            var chiave = $('#ChiaveRicerca').val();
            var url = $('#AvvioRicerca').data()["url"];

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    ambito: ambito,
                    chiave: chiave
                }
            }).done(function (response) {
                $('#EsitoRicerca').removeClass('invisible');
                $('#EsitoRicerca').html(response);
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).on('mouseenter', '#bodyArea tr', function () {
        console.log($(this));
    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you tried `$(document).on('click','table tbody tr', function () {  console.log($(this)); }); `

Comment: Use the `hover` instead of `mouseenter`.

Comment: @Roy tried, but nothing happens. This function is within a `$(document).ready(function() {})` block, and all other functions in the same block (ajax calls to action method) are working.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki the problem is that `click` isn't working either. The events are not being fired at all.

Comment: @DavideVitali Try `$(document).on('mouseenter','#bodyArea tr', function ()...`

Comment: @AswinKumar not working

Comment: @DavideVitali are you using `iframe`s ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki no

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki no, console is empty

Comment: Your code seem's ok. I've tried to recreate your problem in codepen and the mouseenter event is well triggered. https://codepen.io/c4n4r/pen/PLMYVy

Comment: Strange, the other jQuery codes work just fine? could you attach a click event to the whole body then check if it will work.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I've edited the question. Maybe the `.html(response)` method I use for appending the response of the ajax call is wrong?

Comment: No, it looks fine, do you have any duplicate id's in your HTML `#bodyArea` for example?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki No, but it wasn't working even when using classes instead of ids...

Comment: Could you please show us the generated HTML, copy it from the browser developer.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I already did... that is exactly the generated html as taken from the browser

Comment: **SOLVED** it had a `z-index: -1` property in the CSS class, so that the bodyArea was over it and it was actually "invisible". Guys, thank you VERY much for your efforts.

Comment: :D Good job @DavideVitali, Glad to help.